# What is the ideal way to remove `MATCH FULL` from a Foreign Key constraint in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints, alter-table

I just started reading [Seven Databases in Seven Weeks, Second Edition](https://pragprog.com/book/pwrdata/seven-databases-in-seven-weeks-second-edition), and I'm currently completing the `PostgreSQL` lessons.

While creating a new table, I mistakenly included `MATCH FULL` in my Foreign Key constraint.

Here is the command that I used to create the table :

```
CREATE TABLE venues (
  venue_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255),
  street_address text,
  type char(7) CHECK (type in ('public', 'private') ) DEFAULT 'public',
  postal_code varchar(9),
  country_code char(2),
  FOREIGN KEY (country_code, postal_code)
  REFERENCES cities (country_code, postal_code) MATCH FULL
);
```

I'm looking through the [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) documentation, but I can't figure out the proper syntax to remove `MACTH FULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't `ALTER` it ([only](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) `ALTER CONSTRAINT constraint_name [ DEFERRABLE | NOT DEFERRABLE ] [ INITIALLY DEFERRED | INITIALLY IMMEDIATE ]`
). You need rather add `simple match` one and drop old one, like (simplifying the structure):

```
db=# create table p(i int primary key);
CREATE TABLE
db=# create table f(i int references p(i) match full);
CREATE TABLE
db=# \d f
       Table "public.f"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 i      | integer |
Foreign-key constraints:
    "f_i_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (i) REFERENCES p(i) MATCH FULL
```

you see the name and match policy, so now:

```
db=# alter table f add constraint ms FOREIGN KEY (i) REFERENCES p(i) MATCH simple;
ALTER TABLE
db=# alter table f drop constraint f_i_fkey;
ALTER TABLE
db=# \d f
       Table "public.f"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 i      | integer |
Foreign-key constraints:
    "ms" FOREIGN KEY (i) REFERENCES p(i)
```